# Is JSF view tree (UIViewRoot) contains the tag handler(JSTL tags, <ui:include> , <f:xxx>.. etc) information when the view is built?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

When a JSF page is accessed first time, then the jsf view component tree(UIViewRoot) will be created in render response phase and stored on server/client side based on configuration. Is this created UIViewRoot contains the tag handler information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Is this created UIViewRoot contains the tag handler information?*

Nope. Tag handlers are executed when the view is built and therefore not physically present in the resulting component tree. You can basically only find their results in the component tree. E.g. some component being present or absent, or having specific attributes/listeners/converters/validators attached or not.

Do note that the view is not necessarily only built during render response phase. It's during postbacks usually built during restore view phase.

#### See also:

- [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)